# Read contents of system command to dataframe in R

Tags: r, linux

I would like to list all files in a directory (including sub-directories), then read this into a dataframe in R.

Currently I have attempted this with system commands. I have managed to list all files with a command like the one below:

`system("ls -l $(find ~/starting_location/ -type f)")`

But I can't figure out how to then get this into a dataframe in R. I have been trying at least to write this to a text file, then import it, but this hasn't worked either (example below).

`system("ls -l $(find ~/starting_location.prague.UDM/ -type f) > ~/starting_location/file_list.txt")`

The above command is erroring with:

`ls: cannot access starts: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access here: No such file or directory`

Would someone be able to suggest what is wrong with my code line / is there a way to get this directly to R without having to write it to a text file?

Comment: Have you tried `intern = TRUE`?  Also, R has a function called `list.files`.

Comment: It's as simple as `read.table(text = system("ls -l $(find ~/starting_location/ -type f)", intern = TRUE))`  This will give you 9 columns

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I will use the `read.table` approach elsewhere, very useful, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to list the files in a directory, look no further than `list.files`.

```
list.files("~/Documents", recursive = TRUE)
```

The output will be a vector of file names (the argument `full.names = TRUE/FALSE` may be of interest as well), it's then trivial to turn a vector into or append it to a data.frame (`as.data.frame(...)` or `cbind(df, vector)`)

Comment: Perfect thanks, great when the answer is so much simpler than you were expecting :)

Comment: @SamGilbert - So you didn't want `ls -l`, you just wanted `ls`.  They are very different